# PNG encoding with Go is slow

Tags: opencv, go

I'm acquiring frames from my built in webcam with go-opencv. The time it takes to acquire an image from the camera  is ~50ms. The time to encode the PNG is ~300ms.  Encoding a JPEG is 3x faster, but still horribly slow.

Why is this running so slowly?

*Note*:
I've written similar code against NodeJS, executed on the same machine, and have absolutely no problem hitting 30fps w/ additional image processing.  For me, this removes hardware issues from the equation.

My code looks like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "image/png"

    "github.com/lazywei/go-opencv/opencv"
)

camera := opencv.NewCameraCapture(0)
if camera == nil {
    panic("Unable to open camera.")
}
defer camera.Release()

for {
    if camera.GrabFrame() {
        img := camera.RetrieveFrame(1)
        if img != nil {
            frame := img.ToImage()
            buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
            png.Encode(buffer, frame)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Unable to capture frame")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider just saving the mat with [`imwrite`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite).  Any performance difference is likely due to copies or due to a different default quality setting on the PNG encoder.

Comment: How exactly is `image/png` implemented? | I'd go with what @Mitch suggests, since OpenCV used LibPNG under the hood. 300ms per image seems a bit excessive when you're able to get 30fps.

Comment: See what happens if you declare buffer (with `var buffer bytes.Buffer` *not*  `new(bytes.Buffer)`) just within your `for` loop.

Comment: @DanMašek, Mitch -- thanks for your suggestions. image/png is a go library and I haven't dug into it's implementation yet.  I might end up doing that.  I'm taking a look at using the Mat directly now.  The fact that the acquisition alone takes 50ms (~20fps at best) is raising concerns for me to.

Comment: @dlowe I gave that a shot but the results were negligible.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Go's standard image handling packages are implemented in a generic and safe, but slow, way IIRC. You may be better served to look for something faster, but less flexible.

Comment: Why would you are declaring a buffer on every iteration of that loop?
Move it to outside of the loop and preallocate a buffer large enough, this should solve your problem.

Comment: @navossoc Thanks for the idea, unfortunately, as noted the problem is with (1) The image acquisition @ 50ms and (2) The PNG encoding time @ ~300ms.  This is a good suggestion for possible late-stage optimization, but in this case the time to allocate the buffer is negligible.

Comment: I was trying to setup opencv into my windows here to make some tests, but no lucky... sourceforge is down for all day long and I don't have mingw installed.

Comment: Gocv have function called imencode and it will encode to png ucing c++ under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar.  It's been a while since I've looked at this, but I believe my final implementation ended up using libjpeg-turbo.  I as able to get decent quality and compression at ~30-35fps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disabling compression improves encoding performance by an order of magnitude on my machine. That may be a start if you don't want to look for png packages outside the standard library.

I also tried [the BufferPool](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#EncoderBufferPool) (new in Go 1.9), but it didn't make a difference compared to an encoder with a nil BufferPool. Perhaps I did it wrong. The docs are unfortunately very, erm, concise.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkPNG_Encode(b *testing.B) {
    img, buf := loadImage(b)

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            buf.Reset()
            png.Encode(buf, img)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPNG_Encoder(b *testing.B) {
    img, buf := loadImage(b)
    enc := &png.Encoder{}

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            buf.Reset()
            enc.Encode(buf, img)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPNG_Encoder_NoCompression(b *testing.B) {
    img, buf := loadImage(b)
    enc := &png.Encoder{
            CompressionLevel: png.NoCompression,
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            buf.Reset()
            enc.Encode(buf, img)
    }
}

func loadImage(b *testing.B) (image.Image, *bytes.Buffer) {
    // foo.png PNG 1920x1053 1920x1053+0+0 8-bit sRGB 251KB 0.000u 0:00.000
    f, err := os.Open("foo.png")
    if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
    }

    img, err := png.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    // grow the buffer once
    (&png.Encoder{CompressionLevel: png.NoCompression}).Encode(buf, img)

    return img, buf
}
```

Again, this was on my machine with a roughly 1920x1080 pixel image -- a random screenshot; not sure how much this will differ from, say, a photo. YMMV.

```
$ go test -v -bench . -benchmem 
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkPNG_Encode-8                         10         119289121 ns/op          884964 B/op         38 allocs/op
BenchmarkPNG_Encoder-8                        10         118001658 ns/op          884932 B/op         37 allocs/op
BenchmarkPNG_Encoder_NoCompression-8         100          13050664 ns/op          807156 B/op        212 allocs/op
```

It's interesting that no compression causes many more allocations than with compression though.

Comment: This answer not only answers the question but also has a wealth of information to get me moving in the right direction. Thanks for all the effort you put into this!

Answer (score -1):

> Why is this running so slowly?

Measure! Go has nice profiling tools built in e.g. into `go test`.

Most probably it is the PNG encoder which is pure, "unoptimized" Go. If this is not fast enough for you you might want to consider contributing a faster PNG encoder.

Comment: This should have added as a comment not a separate post.